# PHP gd library apparently installed but not functioning

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails, fatal-error, undefined-function

I **can’t get gd library (php_gd2.dll) working with windows8x64, localhost running php5.5 on Apache 2.4**.

I commented out the "`;`" in "php.ini" file located in the main php installation directory and the command `php -m` also shows that the module is loaded.

However, when I try to use it, or try the function `gd_info()`, I get a fatal error saying it was a call to an undefined function.

Example: "`Fatal error: Call to undefined function gd_info() in C:\webserver\www\gd.php on line 2`"

And also, there is no GD section in the information displayed when called to `phpinfo()` .

Context : I'm trying to make a gallery page using Lightbox that uses GD to generate thumbnails automatically. But the call for the respective gd function also is not recognised.

php.ini after enabling gd:

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=ext\php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
```

Can someone propose a solution ?

Comment: Did you restart your Apache?

Comment: *"I commented out the ";" in "php.ini" file"* Do you mean you removed the ";"?  (Don't *describe* what you did. *Show* what you did--paste the relevant lines from your php.ini.)  Which php.ini does phpinfo() say you're using? Look for the value of "Loaded Configuration File".

Comment: The value for "Loaded Configuration File" is "C:\webserver\php\php.ini". I have added the lines from php.ini to the question.